# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paypal'

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm using,

***Python: 3.8, 
Django: 3.0,
django-paypal: 1.0.0***

I'm trying to implement a simple Payment Gateway using ***Django-Paypal*** lib.

And I'm getting this error during the migration.....

```
    (project-venv) PS J:\jaimin (E)\Programming Practice\Django\Payment Gateway using Paypal\simple_ecommerce\django_project> py -3 .\manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jaimi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\jaimi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\jaimi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\jaimi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\jaimi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\jaimi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paypal'
```

And here is my **settings.py**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ecommerce_app',
    'paypal.standard.ipn',  
]
```

What can I do Now?.....

Comment: Make sure that django-paypal is installed in the virtual environment. On Windows I think you can do: `py -3 -m pip freeze`. To install it, try `py -3 -m pip install django-paypal`.

Comment: I already installed django-paypal in my venv

Comment: Are you sure? What is the output of the pip freeze command? The simplest explanation for `No module named 'paypal'` is that it isn't installed in the current environment.

Comment: `(env) PS J:\jaimin (E)\Programming Practice\Django\Payment Gateway using Paypal\simple_ecommerce> pip list
Package       Version   
------------- ----------
asgiref       3.2.7     
certifi       2019.11.28
chardet       3.0.4     
Django        2.0.2     
django-paypal 1.0.0     
django-payu   0.5     `

Comment: That's not the command I suggested. I think that's using `pip` from a different environment. Note that Django is 2.0.2, not 3.0 as you say in your question.

Comment: But My environment is already activated......so how the pip comes from a different environment ?? And Yes I installed Django 2.0 later to check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Sometimes `pip` doesn't point to the Python you think it does. It's one of the frustrations of Python, there's [a famous xkcd cartoon about it](https://m.xkcd.com/1987/). That's why I always recommend `python -m pip` because it guarantees you are using the same version of Python. I'm not familiar with Windows so can't really help with that, but [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel) say that `py -3 -m pip` will work.

Comment: Anyway, please try the exact command I suggested yesterday and show the result. The worst that can happen is that my theory is wrong and we confirm that Django-paypal is installed correctly in the environment.

Comment: Thanks, bro, it's work. I tried exactly what you have suggested..... thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1):

it is happening because of circular import in **init**.py file
follow the steps :
don't install this ...maybe u have done it ...

```
pip uninstall paypal
```

no need to delete migrations unistall it and reinstall it properly

```
pip install django-paypal
```

don't forget to add " - " in that because this is the reason for that issue ...
this worked for me !
try and give a upvote if works . Thank You in advance

Comment: If he is going to use django-paypal why he should uninstall the django ?

Comment: no sir hey should uninstall paypal only ..not django . i have used this but when comes unistall django---n  then uninstall paypal ----y , actually this worked for me ! so i thought it would be helpful to share .

Comment: yea you are right. I didn't understand why you write pip uninstall django paypal if you want to uninstall the paypal. I mean why you don't write just pip uninstall paypal

Comment: yes sir !  absolutely right.... should i edit the ans ? and upvote if it works !

Comment: If you made an mistake in question or answer editing it is always a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install **django-paypal**.

```
pip install django-paypal
```